# DB Independent Java Programming - Suggestions?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I'm looking to write a java program that has the following requirements:

1. An ability to replace the database in use without changes to the code.
2. I would like to do the maintanence from Java - creating the tables, views etc.
3. Should be able to support complicated queries

JDBC seems like a good starting point, but it seems like the queries may be different for different DBs (for example slight syntax differences create table statements in MySQL, and MSSQL).

The idea (obviously) is to avoid writing the same code specifically for each DB, and rely on a driver to do the dirty work for me.

Is JDBC good enough? Are there other options?

Comment: JDBC is a lousy starting point, even w/o multiple database requirement. The multiple database requirement makes it totally inadequate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**JPA**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) seems to be the optimal choice for you. It works almost-out-of-the-box. Abstracts the direct DB handling away and can be used standalone (without an application server).

JDBC is still a valid option but the development with it is not nearly as DB-agnostic as with JPA (which can be seen as an abstraction layer over JDBC).

[Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html) is a nice example.

Most popular JPA implementations are [**Hibernate**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) and [**Eclipselink**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) with Eclipselink (former TopLink) being the reference implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at Hibernate or another ORM solution.

You can use property files to swap out the db without changes to the code in the simplest case. You may want to look at profiles if you are using Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Two libraries that can help, when Hibernate is an overkill:

1. Table maintenance - CREATE,DELETE (DDL) - [DDLUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/)
2. Creating the SQL queries to retrieve the information - [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)

Comment: This answer is already 10 years old, when jOOQ did not support DDL yet, but today it does, see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/

Answer (score 1):

You should start looking for [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). This is exactly what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a design pattern have a look at this. 
I think it might help

[Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have DB independence, don't put any statements in your code. Instead, store them in an external file.

You could have `mysql.ddl` to start. Then down the road, if you switch to oracle, you're make `oracle.ddl` with the same format as `mysql.ddl` but with different queries.

If your database access is its own project, this is extensible because now other applications that talk to this database also will be able to leverage the existing ddl file you wrote.